# Remove continuous/consecutive initial NA values for each group

Tags: r

I would like to remove the initial consecutive NA's(for Sales and Price only) that appears for each product group, until a first non-NA value appears for each product group.

```
S.No,Product,Date,Sales,Price,Count
1,Product1,1/1/2018,NA,NA,7
2,Product1,2/1/2018,NA,NA,6
3,Product1,3/4/2018,5,1,7
4,Product1,4/4/2018,NA,NA,3
5,Product1,5/5/2018,3,1,6
6,Product1,6/5/2018,2,4,10
7,Product1,7/6/2018,5,9,5
8,Product2,1/1/2018,NA,NA,6
9,Product2,2/1/2018,10,3,5
10,Product2,3/4/2018,NA,NA,2
11,Product2,4/4/2018,8,3,8
12,Product2,5/5/2018,3,6,7
13,Product2,6/5/2018,7,4,6
14,Product2,7/6/2018,10,3,3
15,Product3,2/1/2018,NA,NA,7
16,Product3,3/4/2018,NA,NA,2
17,Product3,4/4/2018,NA,NA,1
18,Product3,5/5/2018,NA,NA,7
19,Product3,6/5/2018,10,7,9
20,Product3,7/6/2018,6,3,7
```

Below is the output i am looking to extract.

```
S.No,Product,Date,Sales,Price,Count
3,Product1,3/4/2018,5,1,7
4,Product1,4/4/2018,NA,NA,3
5,Product1,5/5/2018,3,1,6
6,Product1,6/5/2018,2,4,10
7,Product1,7/6/2018,5,9,5
9,Product2,2/1/2018,10,3,5
10,Product2,3/4/2018,NA,NA,2
11,Product2,4/4/2018,8,3,8
12,Product2,5/5/2018,3,6,7
13,Product2,6/5/2018,7,4,6
14,Product2,7/6/2018,10,3,3
19,Product3,6/5/2018,10,7,9
20,Product3,7/6/2018,6,3,7
```

Would appreciate if someone can help me with the approach to tackle this problem.
Is there any package or function in R, that takes care of this scenario.

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
J

Comment: I think [zoo::na.locf()](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/zoo.pdf) is your friend. Just type `?zoo::na.locf` into console and you probably need the `fromLast` argument to be true.

Comment: I tried it. It's replacing the values, rather than remove the entire row. moreover, i want to apply NA logic only based on two columns (Sales+Price) rather than looking at overall all fields.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, didn't read thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

```
dat%>%
 group_by(Product)%>%
 filter_at(vars(4:5),all_vars(cumsum(!is.na(.))))

# A tibble: 13 x 6
# Groups:   Product [3]
    S.No Product  Date     Sales Price Count
   <int> <fct>    <fct>    <int> <int> <int>
 1     3 Product1 3/4/2018     5     1     7
 2     4 Product1 4/4/2018    NA    NA     3
 3     5 Product1 5/5/2018     3     1     6
 4     6 Product1 6/5/2018     2     4    10
 5     7 Product1 7/6/2018     5     9     5
 6     9 Product2 2/1/2018    10     3     5
 7    10 Product2 3/4/2018    NA    NA     2
 8    11 Product2 4/4/2018     8     3     8
 9    12 Product2 5/5/2018     3     6     7
10    13 Product2 6/5/2018     7     4     6
11    14 Product2 7/6/2018    10     3     3
12    19 Product3 6/5/2018    10     7     9
13    20 Product3 7/6/2018     6     3     7
```